# Is storing email confirmation code in the database necessary?

Tags: web

In the php page can't we just generate a random number using php or md5, store it in a variable and then send it directly to the email address.
Then check if the user has entered the correct code.
I have two database tables one for unconfirmed users and other for confirmed so if the user is confirmed he will be added to the confirmed table and deleted from the table for unconfirmed users.

Comment: Could you show a sample of your table structure and possibly any code you have tried?

Comment: Why not store the users in one table with a column whether they are confirmed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save the value in a variable it only exists as long as the script is running. The PHP script however terminates at the end of the file/request, so all values from any variables are lost. When the user comes back clicking on the confirmation link in the email you have no value available to compare the received confirmation code against with.

This means you need to save the confirmation code for later comparison somewhere on the server. You have several options like "sessions", "files" or "databases". If you don't want to save the confirmation code in the database you can save it somewhere else. But you have to save it somewhere.